# How to calculate /Widths table?

Tags: pdf, winapi, mfc, pdf-generation

My MFC application generates PDF's and now i'm trying to embed TrueType fonts, to embed a font i need to "tell" the font object on the PDF the [Glyph Widths](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G8.1958466),

I'm having trouble getting these values, i already tried using `GetCharABCWidthsFloat` and `GetCharWidthFloat` and combining with [this answer](https://forums.adobe.com/message/1082700#1082700) that says that i need to use the formula `(advance * 1000) / unitsPerEm` (scaling the results of `GetCharWidthFloat` to obtain the advance).

**But i don't understand how would i scale that? is there a winApi function that return these values?**

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***`1 em`*** is equal to ***`12 points`***
[*see reference*](https://websemantics.uk/articles/font-size-conversion/)

---

For `MM_TEXT` mapping mode, font height is defined as:

```
lfHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
//or 
lfHeight = round(PointSize * GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY) / 72.0f);
```

[*see `LOGFONG` documentation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

For example, for desktop screen, at 100% DPI, `GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY)` returns `96`. In this case we have:

> 1em = 16, at 100% DPI
>      or
>      1em = 20, at 125% DPI
>      or
>      1em = 24, at 150% DPI

```
double inch_per_pixel_y = (double)dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY);

int size_em = 1;
int size_from_em = (int)round(size_em * inch_per_pixel_y / 6.0f);
printf("size_from_em %d\n", size_from_em);

size_em = (int)round(size_from_em * 6.0f / inch_per_pixel_y);
printf("size_from_em %d\n", size_em);
```

Note that we loose a lot of precision here. Maybe that's the reason for PDF's multiplication with factor 1000.

Use `dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX)` for width calculations.